# DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE on a block creates cache records for every image style on page.. Totally ruins cache. [Fixed: Happens when images are missing]

Tags: caching

I'm leaving this here in case someone searches.. These images weren't on my dev but when I copied them over, the cache stopped getting polluted. Woohoo.

When I enable DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE, my cache is getting polluted by dozens of almost duplicate records of the block, but with cids like the following.

```
custom_home_panes:custom_home_panes_news_group:framework:en:u.7094:http://270717.dd:8083/sites/default/files/styles/panopoly_image_full/public/badges/reading-girl-copy.png?itok=vPf92p1v
```

If you scroll right, you'll see the image, reading-girl-copy.png, is one of about 60 images on the page and it's in a different block that I'm not even caching yet.

Inside the blob for each of these records, the pager for the block I'm caching inexplicably takes on the href of these various images on the page..

```
<li class="pager-current">1 of 3</li>
<li class="pager-next last"><a title="Go to next page" href="/sites/default/files/styles/tasklist_user/public/pictures/picture-7573-1502273926.png?itok=70XVamao&amp;destination=sites/default/files/styles/tasklist_user/public/pictures/picture-7573-1502273926.png&amp;page=1">next ›</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

The below record is the only one I want for this block.. It's per user per page.

```
custom_home_panes:custom_home_panes_news_group:framework:en:u.7094:http://270717.dd:8083/node/2435
```

I can only pursue an extreme cache clearing policy if the cache isn't polluted so any help would be great. I'm at a total loss as to why this would happen.

Thanks.